# Show style of button according to row val

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, datatable

I have two button, 'Set' and 'Get' in the data table for every row. There is a hidden row that show the status of individual records in data table.

I want to be able to set disabled according to that hidden row value. However it only work for the first row of the table. Any advice?

```
    <td><a href="<c:url value='{id}' />" id="setButton" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs custom-width">Set</a></td>

    <td><a id="getButton" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs custom-width">Get</td>
<td style="display:none;"><div id="status">${active}</div></td>

$(document).ready(function() {

              if ($('#status').html() == 'true') {

                  $("#setButton").attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity',0.5);

              } 

              else if ($('#status').html() == 'false'){
                  $("#getButton").attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity',0.5);
              }

            });
```

Comment: Use `class` in your buttons instead of `id`, if you use same `id` for more than one buttons it will not work.

Comment: okay but i already have a styling class inside of these button, how do i add in to use it? @SaidSuleimanJuma

Answer (score 0):

All of your `<a>` have the same Id's, it's not correct in HTML (IDs must be unique).

Use a class instead like `class="getButton"` and `class="setButton"` and with  jQuery use:

```
    $('.getButton').each(function(){
        $("#getButton").attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity', 0.5);
     )
```

And the same for the `setButton`

Comment: but i already have a styling class in it. How do i incorporate this in there?

Comment: @lel are you looking for `.addClass()` ? https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: @Sebastien think you meant `$(this).attr...`

Comment: @freedomn-m er cause i have a class that is to style the word to look like a button so how do i add in another class to use for this?

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes sure, little mistake use this instead $(this).attr(..) after the each. Just add another class, you can add as many class as you want in an HTML element.

Comment: hmm i tried to add your method in but it's not working @SebastienNapo

Comment: @lel try this `(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#status').html() == 'true') {
        $('.setButton').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity', 0.5);
         })
    } else {
        $('.getButton').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity', 0.5);
         })
    }
})`

Comment: @SebastienNapo the button is disable now but the other row seems to just follow the first row instead of having their own individual disabled button

Comment: Oh ok, didn't see the div too .... Delete the `<div id="status">` and change it to `<div class="status">` and then use this code `(document).ready(function() { 
    $('tr').each(function(){
        var status = $(this).find(td[class="status"]).text();
        if(status === 'true'){
            $(this).find('a .setButton').attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity', 0.5); 
        } else {
            $(this).find('a .getButton').attr('disabled','disabled').css('opacity', 0.5); 
        }
    })
})`

Comment: @SebastienNapo there seems to be an error on $(this).find(td[class="status"]).text();

Comment: Yes, my bad i did a mistake use `var status = ($(this).find('div.status').text());` instead and it will work now normally

Comment: Is you'r problem fixed ? In this case i will update my original answer.